# how to get the proritity in java code

Tags: android, android-manifest

In the AndroidManifest.xml, I can add the priority attributes in , I want to know if I can get the value of priority use code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about intent filters is not exposed via `PackageManager`, so, AFAIK, there is no way to access the priority.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API to achieve this, but you can read the AndroidManifest file of any application (including secured ones) and parse out the information yourself.